# Mantain button disabled with Localstorage & jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, local-storage

I am trying to mantain a button disabled (even when user close or refresh the browser) with localstorage and jq but I have not been able to do...
I have managed to create a permanent favourite list, but what I want is disabling the option of creating new favorite when this one has already created.

Here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>

<title>Marcadores</title>

<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $ul = $('#bookmarks');

  //get items from local storage
  if(localStorage.getItem('links')){
   $ul.html(localStorage.getItem('links'));
  }

  $('#cita01').click(function () {
    $('#bookmarks').append('<li><a href="#">Esta es la cita número 1</a><button class="eliminar01">remove</button></li>');
    localStorage.setItem('links', $ul.html());
    $("#cita01").attr('disabled', true);
  });


  //remove item
  $("#bookmarks").on('click','.eliminar01',function () {
      if (confirm("¿Estás seguro de eliminar este favorito?")) {
        $(this).parent().remove();
        //save changes to localstorage
        localStorage.setItem('links', $ul.html());

        $("#cita01").attr('disabled', false);
    }   
    return false;
  });
});
</script>


<style>
#cita01{
    width: 60px;
    height: 40px;
    background: green;
}

.eliminar01{
    width: 60px;
    height: 40px;
    background: red;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="wrapp">

    <h1>Bookmarks</h1>
    <ul id="bookmarks"></ul>
    </div>

    <div id="grupo">
        <h1>Quotes</h1>

        <div class="quote">
            <p>L isjf sldzh valshlsah akuhcEbitat ut la soluptatem re sequae nis commodit re volori res atium aliquunt utas apediti qui tetus cus, consedi ctotatem quod es mollabo restibe rchiti ressit hiti officie nimolup.</p>
        <button id="cita01">Add</button>
        </div>

 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am sure that the problem is here: `$("#cita01").attr('disabled', false);`

---

Anybody could help me with this issue?
Thank you so much in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

As you guessed, it is right. Change the below:

```
$("#cita01").attr('disabled', false);
```

To:

```
$("#cita01").removeAttr('disabled');  // or
$("#cita01").prop('disabled', false);
```

The `.attr()` is only used to set the values. It still sets `disabled="false"`, but the browser renders it as disabled. You must either use the new `.prop()` and set `false` or you should use the old `.removeAttr()` instead.

**Quick fix:** Replace all `.attr()` with `.prop()`.